# typeorm seed and factories

Tags: typescript, typeorm, ts-node

I installed typeorm-seeding and @types/faker, then I created `src/database/seeds/user.seed.ts` and `src/database/factories/user.factories.ts`.

Here's the user seed:

```ts
import { Factory, Seeder } from "typeorm-seeding";
import { User } from "../../entities/User";

export default class CreateUsers implements Seeder {
  public async run(factory: Factory): Promise<any> {
    const user = new User();
    user.firstname = "rme";
    user.lastname = "rume";
    user.email = "aba@sdad.com";
    await user.save();
  }
}
```

user factories:

```ts
import Faker from "faker";
import { define } from "typeorm-seeding";
import { User } from "../../entities/User";

define(User, (faker: typeof Faker) => {
  const gender = faker.random.number(1);
  const firstName = faker.name.firstName();
  const lastName = faker.name.lastName();
  const email = faker.internet.email();
  const password = faker.internet.password();

  const user = new User();
  user.firstname = firstName;
  user.lastname = lastName;
  user.email = email;
  user.password = password;
  return user;
});
```

When I try to start seed or factories with

> ts-node src/database/factories/user.factories.ts (or user.seed.ts)

I am getting error:

> [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"

How can I fix this? And how can I add a seeder or factories with command line. Also what I must add in `package.json` scripts?

Also how can I run seeder or factories?

I tried this for seed run but it doesn't work:

> "seed": "ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm-seeding/dist/cli.js seed -d ./src/db.ts"

When I run yarn seed I get the following error:

> Unknown argument: d